# Unwanted replacement of html entities by BeautifulSoup

Tags: html, utf-8, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, html-entities

I have some html containing mml that I am generating from Word documents using MathType.  I have a python script that uses BeautifulSoup to prettify it, but the problem is it takes something like `&#x2220;` and turns it into the actual byte sequence `0xE2 0x88 0xA0`   which is the ∠ symbol.  This is a problem because `0xE2 0x88 0xA0` won't display as ∠ in the browser. Instead the browser interprets it as a series of latin characters.  This is happening with all the math entities as well, such as Δ ∠ − +... etc.

I looked through the BeautifulSoup documentation and I can see how to turn entities into the byte sequences, but I'm not using that command;  all I'm using is prettify().  And I didn't see a way in the BeautifulSoup documentation to not turn entities into byte sequences.

Does anyone know if there's a setting in BeautifulSoup to tell it not to change entities to byte sequences?  I hope so because it seems kind of dumb to have to undo the damage after prettify runs :)

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed part of the BeautifulSoup documentation.  The default output formatters do the described behaviour: they turn html entities into the unicode characters.  So, this behaviour can be changed by using a different output formatter. (D'oh)

"You can change this behavior by providing a value for the formatter argument to prettify(), encode(), or decode()...."

So if I pass in the `formatter="html"` Beautiful Soup will convert Unicode characters to HTML entities whenever possible!  Yay!  Thank you Beautiful Soup!

(And they have such great documentation.  Pity I didn't read the whole thing sooner. :$)