# Convert BeautifulSoup NavigableString to use html entities

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

So BeautifulSoup [parses HTML entities into Unicode upon reading input](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters). I can [convert these back to HTML entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15840158/unwanted-replacement-of-html-entities-by-beautifulsoup) if I use `.prettify(formatter='html')` on an HTML element.

But the `NavigableString` class doesn't have a `.prettify()` method. I want to turn a `NavigableString` into a string containing the proper HTML entities. How can I do this?

The only way I can think of is surround it with a fake `<a>` tag, use `.prettify()` on the tag, and strip out the beginning and ending characters from the resulting string.

Comment: incidentally, where's the API docs? I found narrative-style documents but they don't list which classes have which methods. Guess it's time to UTSL. :/

Comment: Could [Unicode, Dammit](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#unicode-dammit) work for what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had to resort to [UTSL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTSL). The corresponding method is [`NavigableString.output_ready()`](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~leonardr/beautifulsoup/bs4/view/head:/bs4/element.py#L643).

```
>>> u=BeautifulSoup('&alpha;')
>>> u
<html><body><p>╬▒</p></body></html>
>>> u.p.contents[0]
u'\u03b1'
>>> u.p.contents[0].output_ready(formatter='html')
u'&alpha;'
```

Comment: I was only able to find this answer after I UTSL'd and googled for reference of this function. :|